# Extensions over finite fields

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $K$ and $L$ be extensions of a finite field $F$ of degrees $n$ and $m$,respectively.

How do I show that $KL$ has degree
$\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$ over $F$ and $K\cap F$ has degree $\gcd(m,n)$ over $F$?

Comment: **Don't yell!**

Comment: Since you've done it twice now: all capital letters, on the internet, is the equivalent of shouting. Rather a rude way of trying to call attention, don't you think?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** A field of order $p^n$ is contained in a field of order $p^m$ if and only if $n|m$. $KL$ is the *smallest* field that contains both $K$ and $L$, and $K\cap F$ is the *largest* field contained in both $K$ and $L$. Translate the inclusion statements into divisibility statements.